# Reasoning about Degree of Polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

How can you show that f is a polynomial of degree ≤ 2 if and only if its Hessian is constant

Comment: Should perhaps this question be asked on Mathematics SE?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this in the case of a polynomial of one variable. I think the answer will then be clear.